# How to scramble string C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I write the code to scramble word I am create simple game jumble

```
         string jumble = theWord;
         int length = jumble.Count();
         for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
         {
             int index1 = (rand.Next() % length);
             int index2 = (rand.Next() % length);

             char  temp =jumble[index1];
             jumble = jumble.Replace(jumble[index1], jumble[index2]);
             jumble = jumble.Replace(jumble[index1], temp);

         }
```

update  the code

```
         string jumble = theWord;
         int length = jumble.Count();
         for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
         {
             int index1 = (rand.Next() % length);
             //int index2 = (rand.Next() % length);

         char temp = jumble[index1];
         jumble[i] = jumble[index1 - 1];
         jumble[i] = temp;

         }
```

> Error 1   Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to
>   -- it is read only

Comment: Look up [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle). I would treat the data as `IList<char>` (or some variation of) for simplicity.

Comment: `Error 1 Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` that's why You should use StringBuilder instad of string. Is You want to use `string` You should convert it `ToCharArray()`, set char value by index in this array and after that create `new string(array)` and pass your char `array` as parameter to constructor.

Comment: P.S. You use `String.Replase()` method in wrong context. This method replaces ALL symbols or strings, defined by first parameter with symbol or string in second parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
         StringBuilder jumbleSB = new StringBuilder();
         jumbleSB.Append(theWord);
         int lengthSB = jumbleSB.Length;
         for (int i = 0; i < lengthSB; ++i)
         {
             int index1 = (rand.Next() % lengthSB);
             int index2 = (rand.Next() % lengthSB);

             Char temp = jumbleSB[index1];
             jumbleSB[index1] = jumbleSB[index2];
             jumbleSB[index2] = temp;

         }

         Console.WriteLine(jumbleSB);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with this one for both clarity and good distribution of permutations (possibly on account of performance):

```
public static class Ext
{
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static string Shuffle(this String str)
    {
        var list = new SortedList<int,char>();
        foreach (var c in str)
            list.Add(rand.Next(), c);
        return new string(list.Values.ToArray());
    }
}
```

- Note about other answers: one is heavily biased, the other one won't give all possible shuffles. These are valid answers though if you don't care about this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
var jumble = new StringBuilder("theWord");
int length = jumble.Length;
var random = new Random();
for(int i=length-1; i>0; i--)
{
    int j = random.Next(i);
    char temp = jumble[j];
    jumble[j] = jumble[i];
    jumble[i] = temp;
}
Console.WriteLine(jumble);
```